# importHtml() and yahoo finance

Tags: html, google-sheets, import

=ImportHtml("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/options","table",1) i dont know what i am doing wrong, I just want to import realtime option chain data into google sheets. This link working fine

=IMPORTHTML("https://www.moneycontrol.com/indices/fno/view-option-chain/NIFTY/2024-03-28","table","2")

but could not get any US option chain data using the importhtml. the money control link above works like a charm and update everyminute and quic, want the same for SPY SPX options. Please help.

I tried a lot of website which provide spy/spx option chain but could not import the option chain using importhtml.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.